# Using ttk.Treeview, how can I get horizontal scrolling to work as expected?

Tags: python, treeview, scrollbar, ttk

Using this Python script, which is my first attempt to learn how `ttk.Treeview` works (the extra copy of autoscroll is just to split the horizontal and vertical callbacks):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Test():
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.win = tk.Toplevel()
    self.win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     

    self.treeFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.win, text='Test Scrolling tk.Treeview')
    self.treeFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nsew')
    self.treeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.treeFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def autoscrollv(sbar, first, last):
        print 'vert first:%s, last:%s' % (first,last)
        first, last = float(first), float(last)
        if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
            sbar.grid_remove()
        else:
            sbar.grid()
        sbar.set(first, last)

    def autoscrollh(sbar, first, last):
        print 'horz first:%s, last:%s' % (first,last)           
        first, last = float(first), float(last)
        if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
            sbar.grid_remove()
        else:
            sbar.grid()
        sbar.set(first, last)

    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.treeFrame, orient="vertical")
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.treeFrame, orient="horizontal")

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.treeFrame, height=10, 
                             yscrollcommand=lambda f, l: autoscrollv(vsb, f, l), 
                             xscrollcommand=lambda f, l: autoscrollh(hsb, f, l))  
    self.tree.column("#0", minwidth=400, stretch=True)

    vsb['command'] = self.tree.yview
    hsb['command'] = self.tree.xview

    self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

    self.tree.insert('', 'end', 'xyz', text='abc'*20)
    for i in range(30):
        self.tree.insert('xyz', 'end', text='%s' % i + 'xyz'*40)

    self.win.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
```

I see the following behavior: When I first run the program, the output looks like this:
[image: initial state].

If I expand the window until the horizontal scrollbar shuts off, it looks like this:[image: last just goes to 1.0]

If I continue to expand the window, here is all the text shown:
[image: closed item width]

My first question is, how can I get `xscrollcommand` to recognize the actual width of the text, rather than using the value for `minwidth`?

Going back to the state in the second image, if I open the item, it goes to this:[image: vscroll on]

My second question is nearly the same as the first.  How do I get it to recognize the new width of the item after it is opened?

If I change `minwidth=400` to `width=400`, the horizontal scrollbar never appears.

Summary: while the vertical scrollbar works as I would expect and reacts to the actual lines of text being displayed (rather than the `ttk.Treeview` setting for height), the horizontal scrollbar only seems to care about the value for `minwidth`.  I thought of using something like below, especially if there is an equivalent for `ttk` themed widgets.  But, the setting for `minwidth` doesn't take effect after populating the tree, although I can change the value for width at that  point.  Is there a way to force a change to `minwidth`?

```
minwidth=tkFont.Font().measure(text)
self.tree.column('#0', minwidth=tcw)
```

Sorry for the extra window; that part of Tkinter confuses me no end...

Comment: It's well-known that Tk's Treeview widget has issues w/ horizontal scrolling.  I just drafted a lengthy question on a particular scenario you might want to look at, on the chance it gives you any ideas:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/49715456/