# Forcing a Tkinter.ttk Treeview widget to resize after shrinking its column widths

Tags: python, tkinter

**Background**

Python-2.7.14 x64, Tk-8.5.15 (bundled)

It is well-documented that the Treeview widget in Tk has a lot of issues, and Tkinter, being a thin wrapper, doesn't do much to deal with them.  A common problem is getting a Treeview in `browse` mode to work correctly with a horizontal scrollbar.  Setting the width of the overall Treeview requires setting the width of each column.  But if one has a lot of columns, this stretches the parent container out horizontally, and doesn't activate the horizontal scrollbar.

The solution that I have found is, at design time, for each column, to set `width` to the desired size you want and cache this value somewhere safe.  When you add, edit, or delete a row, you need to walk the columns and query their current width value, and if it's larger than your cached width, set `width` back to the original cached value and *also* set `minwidth` to the current column width.  The last column needs its `stretch` property set to "True" as well, so it can consume any remaining space left over.  This activates the horizontal scrollbar and allows it to pan the contents of the Treeview appropriately, without changing the width of the overall widget.

Caveat: At *some point*, Tk internally resets `width` to equal `minwidth`, but does **not** force a redraw right away.  You get surprised later on when you change the widget, such as by adding or deleting a row, so you have to repeat the above every time the widget is changed.  This is not a really big issue if you catch all of the places where a redraw can happen.

**Problem**

Changing a property of a Ttk style triggers a forced redraw of the entire application, so the caveat I mentioned above pops up, the Treeview widget expands horizonatlly, and the horizontal scrollbar deactivates.

**Walkthrough**

The below code demonstrates:

```python
# imports
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from tkFont import *

# root
root=Tk()

# font config
ff10=Font(family="Consolas", size=10)
ff10b=Font(family="Consolas", size=10, weight=BOLD)

# style config
s=Style()
s.configure("Foo2.Treeview", font=ff10, padding=1)
s.configure("Foo2.Treeview.Heading", font=ff10b, padding=1)

# init a treeview
tv=Treeview(root, selectmode=BROWSE, height=8, show="tree headings", columns=("key", "value"), style="Foo2.Treeview")
tv.heading("key", text="Key", anchor=W)
tv.heading("value", text="Value", anchor=W)
tv.column("#0", width=0, stretch=False)
tv.column("key", width=78, stretch=False)
tv.column("value", width=232, stretch=False)
tv.grid(padx=8, pady=(8,0))

# init a scrollbar
sb=Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sb.grid(row=1, sticky=EW, padx=8, pady=(0,8))
tv.configure(xscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.configure(command=tv.xview)

# insert a row that has data longer than the initial column width and
# then update width/minwidth to activate the scrollbar.
tv.insert("", END, values=("foobar", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
tv.column("key", width=78, stretch=False, minwidth=78)
tv.column("value", width=232, stretch=True, minwidth=372)
```

The resulting window will look something like this:

[image: Example Treeview widget w/ horizontal scrollbar]

Note that the horizontal scrollbar is active, and that there is a slight overflow of the last column beyond the widget's edge.  The last two calls to `tv.column` are what enable this, but dumping the column properties of the last column, we see that Tk has silently updated `width` and `minwidth` to be the same:

```python
tv.column("value")
{'minwidth': 372, 'width': 372, 'id': 'value', 'anchor': u'w', 'stretch': 1}
```

Changing *any* property of *any* style will trigger a forced redraw of the widget.  For example, the next line sets the `foreground` color to red for a derived Checkbutton style class:

```python
s.configure("Foo2.TCheckbutton", foreground="red")
```

This is the Treeview widget now:

[image: Treeview widget after changing a ttk.Style property]

The problem now is **shrinking** the entire widget back.  The last column can be forced back to its original size by setting `width` to the originally-cached size, `stretch` to "False", and `minwidth` to the maximum column size:

```python
tv.column("value", width=232, stretch=False, minwidth=372)
```

[image: Treeview widget after forcing the column size back to original]

But the width of the Treeview widget did not shrink back.

I've found two possible solutions, both in a bind to the `<Configure>` event, using the last display column:

1. Indicate a change of themes:

   ```
   tv.column("value", width=232, stretch=True, minwidth=372)
   tv.event_generate("<<ThemeChanged>>")
   ```
2. Hide and re-show:

   ```
   tv.grid_remove()
   tv.column("value", width=232, stretch=True, minwidth=372)
   tv.grid()
   ```

Both work because they are the only ways I can find to invoke the internal Tk function `TtkResizeWidget()`.  The first works because `<<ThemeChanged>>` forces a complete recalculation of the widget's geometry, while the second works because Treeview will call `TtkResizeWidget()` if it is in an unmapped state when the column is reconfigured.

The downside to both methods is you can sometimes see the window expand for a single frame and then contract back.  This is why I consider both unoptimal and am hoping that someone else knows of a better approach.  Or at least of a bindable event that happens either before `<Configure>` or before the expansion happens, from which I can use one of the above methods with.

Some references indicating that this has been an issue in Tk for a **long** time:

1. Treeview's issues w/ a horizontal scrollbar on the [Tcl Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/20065) (search for `[ofv] 2009-05-30`).
2. Ticket [#3519160](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/3519160fffffffffffff).
3. [Message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-November/003320.html) on Tkinter-discuss mailing list.

And, the issue is **still** reproducible on Python-3.6.4, which includes Tk-8.6.6.

Comment: option 2 worked fine in my case,  tv.grid_remove(),
set the grid width and on the end show it again with 
tv.grid(),
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/3519160fffffffffffff) has been closed in 04.2020 with this [Fix](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/2222bd76671874e4) and was released in tk 8.6.10. I can confirm that with python 3.10 and tkinter 8.6.12 this bug is not reproducible.

To [check your patchlevel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761906/13629335) with:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

print(root.tk.call("info", "patchlevel"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the update!  I will test locally to be sure, but I worked up a compat shim by stuffing a treeview widget into a canvas widget and making horizontal scroll requests scroll the canvas' x-axis (also required clobbering the treeview's xview_scroll with that of the canvas').  For backwards compat, I'll probably keep that hack in place for older versions of Tk and for 8.6.10+, see about using the Treeview natively.  Hopefully it'll all still work right...

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct of resetting the column widths to initial values is good. Instead of binding those calls to `<Configure>`, which causes flickering because it redraws the screen a second time right after the first call, let's reset the column widths before the first screen redraw so nothing gets changed and no second call is necessary:

```
# imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.font import *

# subclass treeview for the convenience of overriding the column method
class ScrollableTV(Treeview):
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    super().__init__(master, **kw)
    self.columns=[]

  # column now records the name and details of each column in the TV just before they're added
  def column(self, column, **kw):
    if column not in [column[0] for column in self.columns]:
      self.columns.append((column, kw))
    super().column(column, **kw)

  # keep a modified, heavier version of Style around that you can use in cases where ScrollableTVs are involved
  class ScrollableStyle(Style):
    def __init__(self, tv, *args, **kw):
      super().__init__(*args, **kw)
      self.tv = tv

    # override Style's configure method to reset all its TV's columns to their initial settings before it returns into TtkResizeWidget(). since we undo the TV's automatic changes before the screen redraws, there's no need to cause flickering by redrawing a second time after the width is reset
    def configure(self, item, **kw):
      super().configure(item, **kw)
      for column in self.tv.columns:
        name, kw = column
        self.tv.column(name, **kw)

# root
root=Tk()

# font config
ff10=Font(family="Consolas", size=10)
ff10b=Font(family="Consolas", size=10, weight=BOLD)

# init a scrollabletv
tv=ScrollableTV(root, selectmode=BROWSE, height=8, show="tree headings", columns=("key", "value"), style="Foo2.Treeview")
tv.heading("key", text="Key", anchor=W)
tv.heading("value", text="Value", anchor=W)
tv.column("#0", width=0, stretch=False)
tv.column("key", width=78, stretch=False)
tv.column("value", minwidth=372, width=232, stretch=True)
tv.grid(padx=8, pady=(8,0))

# style config. use a ScrollableStyle and pass in the ScrollableTV whose configure needs to be managed. if you had more than one ScrollableTV, you could modify ScrollableStyle to store a list of them and operate configure on each of them
s=ScrollableTV.ScrollableStyle(tv)
s.configure("Foo2.Treeview", font=ff10, padding=1)
s.configure("Foo2.Treeview.Heading", font=ff10b, padding=1)

# init a scrollbar
sb=Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sb.grid(row=1, sticky=EW, padx=8, pady=(0,8))
tv.configure(xscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.configure(command=tv.xview)

# insert a row that has data longer than the initial column width and
# then update width/minwidth to activate the scrollbar.
tv.insert("", END, values=("foobar", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
# we don't need to meddle with the stretch and minwidth values here

#click in the TV to test
def conf(event):
  s.configure("Foo2.TCheckbutton", foreground="red")
tv.bind("<Button-1>", conf, add="+")
root.mainloop()
```

Tested on python 3.8.2, tkinter 8.6